# Flutter - Parse Server SDK - IncludeObject not working with liveQuery

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, parse-server, back4app

I was trying out includeObject method with my livequery in one of my project. I am using [Parse_Server_Sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk) for this back4App database. Also, I am using flutter parse_server_sdk latest version 1.0.26.

What i want is i have a list of events. So whenever a new event is added in my database then it should trigger the subscription method. I have used following code and it works as well. But, only thing i have issue with is i don't get the includedobject i have added in QueryBuilder.

```
QueryBuilder<ParseObject> parseQuery =
        QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject(tblEvents))
          ..whereEqualTo(tblEventUserId, currentUser);
    parseQuery.includeObject([tblOrganizerId]);

    Subscription subscription = await liveQuery.client.subscribe(parseQuery);
    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.create, (value) {
      print("val : ${value}");
      print("val : ${value.runtimeType}");
    });
```

Output :

```
val : {"className":"Group_Events","objectId":"uotQ6BpT4C","createdAt":"2020-08-27T07:18:26.581Z","updatedAt":"2020-08-27T07:18:26.581Z","organizer_id":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Organizer","objectId":"t9M1oyZHh4"},"user_id":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"Hx5xJ5ABxG"},"weight":1}
I/flutter (30335): val : ParseObject
```

I have also evaluated the expression. But, there is only limited pointer data to "tblOrganizerId". I am not getting whole data of that table.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround or a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "ParseLiveListWidget". It should be perfect for this scenario.
You can find an example [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/tree/release/1.0.27/example_livelist).
Additional information is in this [README](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/blob/release/1.0.27/README.md#ParseLiveList).
(Use version 1.0.27 for some important bug fixes.)